System crashes in Ubuntu 24.04
My system keeps crashing after some time of usage and I'm not sure what's the cause.
Errors in log file:
journalctl -p error -b

kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination 
kernel: Bluetooth hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
bluetoothd[936]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialisation failed
bluetoothd[936]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
gdm-password[2559]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
systemd[2578]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-2843.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
systemd[2578]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-2811.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
systemd[2578]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dkeyring\x2dgtk-3117.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

Also Bluetooth and wifi are working (until the time PC is working).
This is how it looks when system crashes.

Trying to open whatever is visible.

Once I got this as well.

